# How does bitcoind choose its data directory?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, raspberry-pi, datadir

Sorry, noob question I am new to anything linux related. I managed to set up bitcoin core just fine on my raspberry pi 4 and I have an external HDD that I want to use as my data directory for the 250 GB or so of blocks (this is not my main storage that I boot from).

Problem is, I have absolutely no idea how the bitcoind program decides on its data directory. I have run 3 or 4 times and I have 3 or 4 different data directories, none of which are on the HDD. How do I tell it where to store the data? Also, where do I put the bitcoin.conf file because it can never seem to find it. I have most of the blockchain pre-installed on my HDD from my windows pc and so I would ideally use that same directory but if thats not possible thats fine, I at least want it on my HDD though. I have followed several guides and nothing has worked for me so far. I appreciate your time for any respones!

Answer (score 4):

Unless explicitly told otherwise, the `datadir` is always placed in `/home/$USER/.bitcoin`, there is no logic for automatically using any location other than this. The configuration file is always in the data directory as `bitcoin.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways of pointing to your data directory is making a change to your bitcoin.conf file (it's usually located in  `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` path)
Add the line:

> datadir = /path_to_your_data_directory

If you're on raspberry Pi I highly suggest reading through the `Raspibolt` documentation, it's step by step installation guide, linking specific chapter related to your question below:
https://stadicus.github.io/RaspiBolt/raspibolt_30_bitcoin.html#prepare-data-directory

Comment: 3 second delta has got to be some sort of new record.

Answer (score 2):

When you start bitcoind, you can specify a non-default data directory:

`$ bitcoind datadir=/your/custom/filepath`

This will override the option set in the `bitcoin.conf` file, if there is one set there.

Answer (score 1):

here i have some example script for UTX token ( bitcoind and the friend )

[example script and manage blockchain](https://github.com/sicute/blockchain)

also in that script include block monitoring using bash and qt compare with public blockchain explore node

Answer (score 0):

The SD card on a Raspberry Pi will not be large enough to accommodate the Bitcoin blockchain.  However, by default the data directory will be /home/$USER/.bitcoin which is on the SD card.  One way to change this to a data directory on an external hard disk drive would be to create a symbolic link to the new directory, as follows:

ln -s /mnt/ext/bitcoin /home/$USER/bitcoin/.bitcoin

Correct the above line to accommodate your pathways.